# Re-coding System Missings in R?

Tags: r, na

Thanks for all of the support so far. I'm making the move from SPSS to R. I have the following SPSS code. Are there ways in R to deal with NAs in the same way as SPSS?

Thanks!

```
FREQUENCIES income.

RECODE income (1 THRU 6 = copy) (else = SYSMIS) INTO 
income2.

FREQUENCIES income2.

*User defined missing.
FREQUENCIES income.

MISSING VALUES income (8, 9).

FREQUENCIES income.

*Remove user defined missing.
MISSING VALUES income ().

FREQUENCIES income.
```

Comment: Pleease show a small reproducible example and your expected output

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Stack Overflow is not a code translation service from one language to another. If you want R help, just describe what you are trying to accomplish with your data. What "ways of dealing with NAs" in particular do you need for your analysis?